# Form validation issue with React-Redux, Yup and formik

Tags: typescript, react-redux, formik, yup

I have an issue when I try to validate input data with Yup using Formik and Redux. Before Redux it was working just fine, but since I extended my application with Redux, Yup is acting like it would be no data in input, but it is there. I'll reduce my code to Only one input but it's the same behavior for every 3 of them

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRKfY.png)

```html
    import CustomTextField from "./CustomTextField";
    import { validationSchema } from "./schemas/schemas";


    const MainForm: React.FC = () => {
      const formValue = useSelector((state: any) => state.form);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{...}}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={() => {
          dispatch(isFormSaved(true));
        }}
      >
        {({ isSubmitting }) => (
          <Form style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
            <CustomTextField
              placeholder="Title"
              name="title"
              type="input"
              value={formValue.title}
            />
            <Button disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
    );
    };

    export default MainForm;
```

and customTextField:

```html
const CustomTextField: React.FC<FieldAttributes<{}>> = ({
  placeholder,
  ...props
}) => {


  const [field, meta] = useField<{}>(props);
  const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : "";
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <TextField
      placeholder={placeholder}
      {...field}
      helperText={errorText}
      error={!!errorText}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={(event: SyntheticEvent) => {
        dispatch(saveForm(event));
    }}
    ></TextField>
  );
};

export default CustomTextField;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dump of `props` and `meta` from the `CustomTextField` component?

Comment: Also, what do you actually have in the `initialValues={{...}}` section?

Comment: initial valuues are

 initialValues={{
          title: "",
          about: "",
          price: "",
          file: null
        }}

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/C3IqXJI)

Comment: It's because it's not from API response, I type manually some dummy data to input so `tuched` is set to true https://gifyu.com/image/7CGV

Comment: I'm just now seeing an important detail in your example.  You're overriding where the field value is being stored.  Before, the field values where being stored in Formik's state, but because you're overriding the change event, and dispatching actions, the field's values are now stored in Redux, which Formik is unaware of and can't see.  If you wanted to store the form's values in both Formik and Redux, you'd need to develop the syncing between the two states, or use a third-party library.  But the React community recommends to keep form state out of Redux.

Comment: Read the paragraph under the ATTENTION section.  https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form